# How to create a flexible vertical line in between two divs?

Tags: css

How do I create a line in between two divs that auto-adjusts its height depending on the gap in between it and the next div? Currently, it looks ok when the div is just a one-liner but when the div's height changes depending on the content, then the line breaks.

[image]

Currently, I have this code:

```
.icon {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.icon:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 58px;
    left: 23px;
    border-left: 2px dashed #CCC;
}
```

Comment: check this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_timeline

Comment: Make sure you mark something as the answer or leave a comment to improve the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just a couple days implemented something like that on https://designsystemmeetup.com/v1.0.0/

A reduced implementation here:
https://codepen.io/dominikwilkowski/pen/KxjPGg

Note in my implementation the image is set to the top not the middle...

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 4.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 3px solid #cccccc;
  left: 1.75rem;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.2rem;
  top: 0;
  width: 3.125rem;
  height: 3.125rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ea iure alias, vitae a vel fugit numquam quidem iusto est eos hic impedit ex odit
      maiores. Sequi earum aspernatur, dignissimos! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus harum et, cumque illum in, fuga
      inventore quo dolore alias atque natus nesciunt, excepturi ducimus ullam laborum. Ratione explicabo, eaque tempora. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, saepe ratione illo, ab deleniti ex, eius similique soluta impedit molestiae quod possimus aliquam. Provident,
      ipsam. Praesentium commodi, laboriosam ex aperiam.
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <h2>Headline 2</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ea iure alias, vitae a vel fugit numquam quidem iusto est eos hic impedit ex odit
      maiores. Sequi earum aspernatur, dignissimos!
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <h2>Headline 3</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ea iure alias, vitae a vel fugit numquam quidem iusto est eos hic impedit ex odit
      maiores. Sequi earum aspernatur, dignissimos! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus harum et, cumque illum in, fuga
      inventore quo dolore alias atque natus nesciunt, excepturi ducimus ullam laborum. Ratione explicabo, eaque tempora. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, saepe ratione illo, ab deleniti ex, eius similique soluta impedit molestiae quod possimus aliquam. Provident,
      ipsam. Praesentium commodi, laboriosam ex aperiam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ea iure alias, vitae a vel fugit
      numquam quidem iusto est eos hic impedit ex odit maiores. Sequi earum aspernatur, dignissimos! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Repellendus harum et, cumque illum in, fuga inventore quo dolore alias atque natus nesciunt, excepturi ducimus ullam laborum. Ratione explicabo,
      eaque tempora. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, saepe ratione illo, ab deleniti ex, eius similique soluta impedit
      molestiae quod possimus aliquam. Provident, ipsam. Praesentium commodi, laboriosam ex aperiam.
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

add **overflow:hidden** for div. and increase the height of the line.

```
.icon:after {
   height:1000px;
}

div{
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Check below code snippet

```css
  
/* Base */
  

 body{
     background:#252827;
   }
#content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Timeline */
.timeline {
  border-left: 4px solid #004ffc;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-family: 'Chivo', sans-serif;
  margin: 50px auto;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-size: 1.03em;
  padding: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 100;
  max-width: 30%;
}
.timeline h1 {
  font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.timeline h2,
.timeline h3 {
  font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.timeline .event {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline .event:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
}
.timeline .event:before,
.timeline .event:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}
.timeline .event:before {
  left: -217.5px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  content: attr(data-date);
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  min-width: 120px;
  font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;
}
.timeline .event:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #004ffc;
  left: -57.85px;
  background: #313534;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  content: "";
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
 
  <ul class="timeline">
    <li class="event" >
      <h3>Dinosaurs Roamed the Earth</h3>
      <p>RAWWWWWWRRR.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="event" >
      <h3>Creative Component Launched</h3>
      <p>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec sed odio dui. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>    
    </li>
    <li class="event">
      <h3>Squareflair was Born</h3>
      <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p> <p>Get ready!</p>    
    </li>
    <li class="event" >
      <h3>Squareflair Today</h3>
      <p>Our success can be measured by lives changed and enhanced by more than eight years of Squarespace-focused service.</p>    
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you expect people to learn if you don't explain your answer?